# Why am I getting -1 as exit status of ChannelSftp all the time?

Tags: java, ssh, sftp, jsch

I want to monitor the state of my channel but it keeps printing -1. 
I used it in a code and it is working just fine. It transfers the files successfully. It should return 0 but it keeps returning -1. Any idea why?

```
channelSftp = (ChannelSftp) session.openChannel("sftp");
this.timeout = session.getTimeout();
System.out.println(channelSftp.getExitStatus());
channelSftp.connect();
System.out.println(channelSftp.getExitStatus());
channelSftp.cd(path);
System.out.println(channelSftp.getExitStatus());
is = channelSftp.get(filename);
System.out.println(channelSftp.getExitStatus());
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`Channel.getExitStatus`](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/Channel.html#getExitStatus--) returns an exit status of the channel, not of the previous SFTP request. Until the channel is closed, the exit status is undefined (that's what the `-1` indicates):

> retrieves the exit status of the remote command corresponding to this channel. The exit status is only available for certain types of channels, and **only after the channel was closed** (more exactly, just before the channel is closed).

All the methods like the `ChannelSftp.connect`, the `ChannelSftp.cd`, etc, throw an exception, when they fail. There's no need to check for "status" after you call them.

Comment: By using `.close`? It sends a request to close the channel to the server. The exit status is populated only after the server responds. If you call `.getExitStatus` immediately after calling `.close`, it won't be populated yet. Anyway, what are you trying to do?

Comment: Im developing an app that involves sftp using jsch and for debugging and logging purposes, I need the exit codes. I got the exit codes for the exec channel perfectly and even customized some. And yeah I used .close.

Comment: exit code for the ChannelSftp channelSftp  instance I created

Comment: What for? It does not return anything useful, unless it terribly fails to even start.